# Adicionar Class se corresponder a um padrão

Tags: javascript, html

Eu estou a tentar fazer com que adicione uma `Class` à um elemento através do seu ID caso ele seja um certo gênero de padrão.

```js
if (/^([0-9]{4}[\-]?[0-9]{3})$/.test('#codigoPost')) {
  $('#codigoPost').removeClass("is-invalid");
  $('#codigoPost').addClass("is-valid");
} else {
  $('#codigoPost').removeClass("is-valid");
  $('#codigoPost').addClass("is-invalid");
}
```

```css
.is-valid(
border: 1px solid red;
)

.is-invalid(
border: 1px solid green;
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div>
    <label class="label-noPadding" for="codigoPost">Código Postal</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="codigoPost" id="codigoPost" pattern="[0-9]{4}[\-]?[0-9]{3}" placeholder="0000-000" required="true">
  </div>
</form>
```

Basicamente, se for do gênero "1234-123", "2222-333" ou "9876-543". 4 números, seguido de um "-" e seguido de 3 números adiciona a `class`.
Mas não estou a ver o que estou a fazer mal aqui, ele dá sempre `false` entrando no `else`. Agradeceria ajuda.

Comment: coloca o resto o html também se não fica impossível de testar seu snippet pelo fato de não existir nenhum elemento com esse #id

Comment: @Lodi Assim fica melhor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coloquei a função no evento de `onkeyup`, troquei o tipo do `input` estava `number` para `text`.
*Motivo:* Como `number` toda vez que entrar um carácter que não seja numero invalida o valor no `input`, como você espera um `-` não pode ser `number`. 
Acertei o `style` que estava com `()` ao invés de `{}` e coloquei a cor vermelha no `invalid` e a verde no `valid`, tirei o `outline` do `input` para ver melhor no snippet

```js
function teste(){
    var self = $(this),
        valor = self.val(),
        result_teste = /^([0-9]{4}[\-]?[0-9]{3})$/.test(valor);
    console.log( valor, result_teste );
    if ( result_teste ) {
      self.removeClass("is-invalid").addClass("is-valid");
    } else {
      self.removeClass("is-valid").addClass("is-invalid");
    }
 }

 $('#codigoPost').on('keyup',teste);
```

```css
input{ outline:none; }
.is-valid{
border: 1px solid green;
}

.is-invalid{
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div>
    <label class="label-noPadding" for="codigoPost">Código Postal</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="codigoPost" id="codigoPost" pattern="[0-9]{4}[\-]?[0-9]{3}" placeholder="0000-000" required="true">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado acho que o meu maior problema era ter o tipo como ```number``` e nao como ```text``` mas simplifico o codigo com isto muito obrigado :)